# Data replacement using MongoReactiveRepository nad project reactor

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I try to replace data from mongo if it's different than already stored data, and i wrote this code

```
public <T> Mono<Void> replaceObjectsIfNotAlreadyStored(List<T> products, ReactiveCrudRepository<T, String> objRepository) {
    return objRepository.findAll()
            .collectList()
            .filter(productsList -> !areAlreadyInDb(productsList, products))
            .flatMap(products1 ->  objRepository.deleteAll()).
            doOnSuccess(products1 -> objRepository.saveAll(products).collectList());
}
```

But when i'am trying to test it

```
   @Test
public void replaceObjectsIfNotAlreadyStoredNeg() {
    repository.saveAll(products)
            .collectList()
            .block();

    checksumService.replaceObjectsIfNotAlreadyStored(otherList, repository).block();
    List<Product> current = repository.findAll()
            .collectList()
            .block();

    assertEquals(current, otherList);
    repository.deleteAll()
            .block();
}
```

the current list is empty instead of same like otherList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you are attempting to trigger some async processing inside a doOn* method, which unlike flatMap doesn't subscribe to the flux/mono inside. you have to subscribe somehow, and the recommended way is to either use flatMap (if you want to do something when there is a result in the previous operator, which I don't believe is the case here) or switchIfEmpty (if the source operator emits nothing, but still succeeds)